# Plotting a png as background on a Log scale Plot

Tags: matplotlib, logging, png, axes

I have created an X/Y plot with data ranging for x=0.1 to 10 and Y=1.0 to 1000. Both scales are log10.
I would like to underlay an image that is also scaled to the same log values.
When I plot the png file under the scatter, it scales the png according to the log scale, and distorts the image. How do it stop it doing that? 
[This is what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G0WO0.png) [This is what the background should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a5hMw.png)

```
sbt=plt.imread('/Users/????????/Desktop/SBT2.png')
fig, axs=plt.subplots()

axs.plot(df['Rf'],df['qc/pa'],'bo', linewidth=0.2)
axs.set_yscale('log')
axs.set_xscale('log')
axs.set_xlim(0.1,10)
axs.set_ylim(1.0,1000)
axs.set_xlabel('Friction Ratio, Rf %')
axs.set_ylabel('Cone Resistance, (qc/pa)')
axs.imshow(sbt,aspect='auto',extent=(0.1,10,1,1000))
```

Comment: Try setting the xlim and ylim after `imshow`

Comment: @Sheldore. Same results sadly.

Comment: See https://matplotlib.org/2.0.0/users/whats_new.html#non-linear-scales-on-image-plots